# Convergence of $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {3^k}{5^k + 1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

> Show the convergence of the following series:
>
> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac {3^k}{5^k + 1}$$
>
> - a) Show the monotony of the partial sums
> - b) estimate upwards
> - c) remember the geometric series (I do not know how to use that here.)

---

The following is what I have done so far:

To show by induction: $a_{k+1} < a_k \forall k \in \mathbb N_0$

Induction start: $n=1$

$a_2= \frac{3^2}{5^2+1}=\frac{9}{25+1}=\frac{9}{26}=\frac{18}{52} < \frac{26}{52}=\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{6}=\frac{3^1}{5^1+1}=a_1$

Induction step:

$$\begin{align}
a_{k+1}&<a_k \\
\equiv \frac{3^{k+1}}{5^{k+1}+1} &< \frac{3^k}{5^k+1} \\
\equiv \frac{3^{k+1}}{5^{k+1}} &< \frac{3^k}{5^k} \\
\equiv \frac{3^{k+2}}{5^{k+1}} &< \frac{3^{k+1}}{5^k} \\
\equiv \frac{3^{k+2}}{5^{k+2}} &< \frac{3^{k+1}}{5^{k+1}} \\
\equiv \frac{3^{k+2}}{5^{k+2}+1} &< \frac{3^k+1}{5^{k+1}+1} \\
\equiv a_{k+2} &< a_{k+1} \\
\end{align}$$

To Show: $|a_k|= a_k$

$$
\begin{align}
|a_k| &= |\frac{3^k}{5^k+1}| \\
      &= \frac{|3^k|}{|5^k+1|} \\
      &= \frac{3^{|k|}}{5^{|k|}+|1|} \\
      &= \frac{3^k}{5^k+1} \\
      &= a_k
\end{align}$$

Because of the induction I can conclude that the sequence $\lim_{k \to \infty}a_k$ becomes smaller and smaller. 
And because of $|a_k|=a_k$ are all values $\forall k \in \mathbb N$ positive.

$\Rightarrow $ The sequence  $a_k$ is monotically decreasing. 
$\Rightarrow $ The series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ is monotically increasing.

$$
\begin{align}
a_k = \frac{3^k}{5^k+1} &< \frac{3^k}{5^k}  \\
                        &< \frac{3^k}{3^k}  \\
                        &= 1 \\
\end{align}$$

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} 1 = 1$$

And thus: $\exists N \in \mathbb N$, such that

$$|a_k| \le 1, \forall \quad k \ge N$$

Using the direct comparison test there can be concluded that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{a_k}$ converges.

> **Question**: Is my proof correct?

Comment: I have edited my answer; please see the new version where some errors in your work are addressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that a geometric series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} r^k$ converges $\iff$ $|r|<1$.

Let $b_k=\left(\dfrac 35 \right)^k$.

For every $k \ge 0$, we have $0<a_k \le b_k$. Thus if $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k$ converges, by the comparison test $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$ converges too. And we know that $b_k$ converges because it is a geometric series with $|r|<1$.

---

A few comments about your work. You wrote

$\dfrac{|3^k|}{|5^k+1|} =\dfrac{3^{|k|}}{5^{|k|}+|1|}$

But $|3^k|=3^{|k|}$ is in general not true. Consider that $|3^{-2}|=\dfrac 19$ , while $3^{|-2|}=9$. What should have been written is $|3^k|=3^{k}$, because for any $k$ we have $3^k>0$.

There is also a mistake in the denominator; you seem to think that $|a+b|=|a|+|b|$. But this is again not true in general. Consider $a=1, b=-1$. It is actually true that $|a+b| \le |a|+|b|$, with equality holding $\iff$ $a, b$ are both the same sign, or if both or one of them is zero.

You also wrote at the bottom that there is some $N$ such that when $k\ge N$, $a_k<1$, so therefore the series converges by the comparison test. But that is not at all what the comparison test says. Consider $c_k = \dfrac 1k$. There does exist an $N$ such that $k \ge N \implies c_k<1$ (namely $N=2$), but $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac 1k = 1 + \dfrac 12 + \dfrac 13 + \dfrac 14 + \cdots$ is the harmonic series, which famously diverges.

Comment: I thought it holds for Series there is $k \in \mathbb N_0$ ?

Comment: @jublikon A series converges if the sequence of partial sums, $S_n = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots + a_n$  converges (One of many way to show that a sequence converges is to show that it is monotonic and bounded). But just showing that $a_k$ converges doesn't mean that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k$. It is neccesary for $a_k$ to converge to zero in order for $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k$ to converge, but it is not sufficient.

Comment: As I said in the post the sequence $1, \dfrac 12, \dfrac 13, \dfrac 14, \cdots$ converges to zero but the sum $1+\dfrac 12 + \dfrac 13 + \dfrac 14+\cdots$ does not converge.

Answer (score 4):

For a) you have to show, that $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k<\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} a_k$, which is kinda clear, since $a_k>0$ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then stipulate $\frac{3^k}{5^k+1}<\frac{3^k}{5^k}$ and use the geometric series. With the comparision test we get that the series converges.

But this can be also done immediatly. We kinda do not need the step a).

Comment: Can you explain how to use the geometric series here?

Comment: Sure. The geometric series is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^k=\frac{1}{1-q}$, for $|q|<1$. Here we have $q=\frac{3}{5}<1$. Which leaves us with $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\frac{3}{5})^k=\frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{5}}=2,5$

Answer (score 0):

you have $\frac{3^k}{5^k+1} < \frac{3^k}{5^k}= \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^k$ than it follows $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k  = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^k}{5^k+1} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^k}{5^k} =  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{k+1}=\frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{5} } \right) = \frac{3}{2}$$

So you showed that a bigger series converges and after the comparison test  you are done.